# How do I create a .Net webservice call which accepts a List<Int64> as an input parameter?

Tags: .net, .net-core, swagger

I'm defining a .Net webservice using .net-core 2.0 and the Swagger framework.

I want to be able define a webservice call that accepts an array of integers.

**Consider the following definition:**

```
[HttpGet("UserRecords/{userIds}")]
public IEnumerable<UserRecord> GetUsers(List<Int64> userIds)
{
}
```

This compiles and runs successfully.
But when I examine the userIds parameter, it is a zero length list.

I know a workaround would be to pass the userIds in as a comma delimited list
and then reconstruct the collection.

Can someone please advise me on the correct way write this definition using either an array or `List<>`?

Thanks, JohnB

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get a list of userIds as part of the URL path. Try this code:

```
[HttpGet("UserRecords/multipleUserIds")]
public IEnumerable<UserRecord> GetUsers([FromQuery] List<int> userIds)
{
}
```

Than the url will be something like http://localhost:5000/UserRecords/multipleUserIds?userIds=1&userIds3